# How to Get the value on a specific step closest to my number

Tags: c#, math, calculation

I have an arbitrary numeric value (float), and an arbitrary step (also a float).

I want to find the number on the step that would be the closest to the numeric value, without going the long way (stepping until I reach it)

Example:
The step is 5
The value is 1038

The step would go 0 - 5 - 10 - 15 - ... - 1035 - 1040 - ...

The closest value is therefore 1040. This is very easy to find with a loop just searching for the last value before my number, the first value after, and choose the closer one.

But this is O(n), and I want something faster (sometimes the step is very small and the value very big, and this has to be done extremely fast for UI reactions).

Is there a way to do this with just a calculation, without a loop?

EDIT: There is no need to start at 0. The step can be negative or positive (but a step of -40 would give the exact same result as a step of 40). If it is done through a clever calculation instead of a loop, no start point is required.

English is not my native language. I am well aware that "step" is probably the wrong word, but I can'tt find the right one to explain. I hope my example makes my question clearer.

Edits are welcome if anyone knows how to explain it more clearly (including changing the title)

Comment: What have you tried? share the code

Comment: You can't get better than average N/2 unless you create a hash.  If you are doing it only once the time to create hash is more than the N/2.  Hash only gives improvement if you are doing many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use math to figure it out. First, get the absolute values of `value` and `step`, then determine the numbers on either side of `step` by subtracting `value % step` from `value` for the low number, and adding `step` to the low number for the higher one.

Then just determine which number is closer to `value` and return that (but first multiply it by the sign of `value`):

```
static float GetClosestNumber(float value, float step)
{
    // Get the absolute values of our arguments
    var absValue = Math.Abs(value);
    step = Math.Abs(step);

    // Determing the numbers on either side of value
    var low = absValue - absValue % step;
    var high = low + step;

    // Return the closest one, multiplied by -1 if value < 0
    var result = absValue - low < high - absValue ? low : high;
    return result * Math.Sign(value);
}
```

Here's a little test method and associated class:

```
class Item
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public float Step { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    var testItems = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item {Value = 1038, Step = 5},
        new Item {Value = .8f, Step = .25f},
        new Item {Value = .9f, Step = .25f},
        new Item {Value = -86, Step = -45},
        new Item {Value = -168, Step = -45},
        new Item {Value = -168, Step = 45},
    };

    foreach (var testItem in testItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The closest number to {0}\twhen stepping by {1}\tis {2}", 
            testItem.Value, testItem.Step, GetClosestNumber(testItem.Value, testItem.Step));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You missed the point where he stated that both the value and the step value were floats.

Comment: I admit that this was not specified explicitly in the question, but your answer doesn't handle negative numbers well (and floats can be negative). For example, -86 with step of 45 will give -45, while -90 would be much closer

Comment: One of my test cases, number: -168 and step: 45 gives me -90 for this case (and it really should be -180)

Comment: I will accept it anyway, because I can work around it by only using the positive side (Math.Abs) for both the value and the step, then going back to negative if the original was negative. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @KaitoKid Oh, I see you were using a positive `step` and a negative `value`. I've added a condition to always return zero if `value` and `step` don't have the same sign (since stepping always starts from zero, both `value` and `step` must be on the same side of `0`).

Comment: Actually, since it's done in a math way, there is no reason for the step to start at zero. You could imagine it starts at -infinity. The whole idea of a step is basically just a way of explaining it, there is no start. I would expect -168 and 45 to give the same thing as -168 and -45, which is -180.

Comment: *"there is no reason for the step to start at zero."* Except that your example shows that it starts at `0`...

Comment: That is correct, but as I mentioned, it's just a way of imagining the whole step concept. When we do away with the loop, we no longer need a start point, so we can assume the start point is some number that comes before the value and is still a multiple of step.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I've modified the method to take this into account by using the absolute values of `value` and `step` to determine the numbers on either side of `value`, and then return the closes one multiplied by the sign of `value`...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
        int step = 3;
        int value = 10;

        if ((value % step) == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((value / step) + 1) * step;
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget about 0